# How to prevent iOS Simulator from locking the screen?

Tags: ios-simulator

Since version 8.2, iOS Simulator locks the screen if it's not used for some time. This is very inconvenient for me, and I cannot find any settings to disable screen locking.

Any solution?

Comment: This should be on [AskDifferent.se](http://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I do not see this issue.  The simulated device stays unlocked for me.  If you have modified any preferences, that might be related.  You can try resetting the device to its default state from the 'iOS Simulator Menu'